# Updating table with multiple rows

Tags: mysql, laravel

How can I update multiple rows at the same time by their report_id? My Inventory table looks like this:

```
| id | report_id | product_id | shelf_quantity | display_quantity |
|----|-----------|------------|----------------|------------------|
| 1  | 2         | 12         | 1              | 5                |
| 2  | 2         | 13         | 2              | 6                |
| 3  | 2         | 14         | 3              | 23               |
```

My attempt to solve the problem:

My controller:

function update($id, Request $request) {

```
    $report = Report::find($id);
    $inputs = $request->input('display');

    $report->user_id  = $user_id;
    $report->save();

    //Updating inventory table

    $inventory = Inventory::where('report_id', $report->id)->get();
    foreach($inputs as $key => $value) {        
      $inventory->display = $request->input('display')[$key] ?: 0;
      $inventory->storage = $request->input('storage')[$key] ?: 0;               
      $inventory->save();
    }
```

My web route:

```
Route::put('/reports/{id}', 'ReportController@update');
```

The problem here is that it is only saving the last value that I input.

Additional information

I'm also using the same code in storing new rows and it's working fine. Please see code below:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
 //Adding inventory table
        $new_inventories = new Inventory();

        foreach($inputs as $key => $value) {

            $data[] = [
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'report_id' => $new_report->id,
                'display' => $request->input('display')[$key] ?: 0,
                'storage' => $request->input('storage')[$key] ?: 0,
                'product_id' => $request->product_id[$key],
                'created_at' => $now,
                'updated_at' => $now,
                // 'remark' => $request->remark[$key] ?? null,
            ];
        } 

        Inventory::insert($data);  
        //End of inventory table
}
```

Any form of help would be appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: 
[image]

My form looks like this:

```
<form action="/reports/{{$report->id}}" method="post">
@csrf
{{method_field('PUT')}}
@foreach($products as $product)
<input type="number" name="product_id[]" value="{{ $product->id}}" hidden>
<input type="number" name="storage[]">
<input type="number" name="display[]">
@endforeach
</form>
```

Comment: Show us the form.... DD on $request->input() for your update

Comment: It's obvious that you loop through $input array/collection but you should also loop through the $inventory array/collection to be able to update one row at a time.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with additional information. Also I appreciate the reply. Thank you

Comment: What do you want to update? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: I want to update the shelf_quantity and display_quantity I have tried Inventory::update() and it's the same. And it's only taking the last value on input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update multiple rows in one shot. In this case the best way is to get one by one the items in inventory and update them. So you loop through $request->input('product_id'), get the Inventory model for that product_id and $report->id, update and save.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($request->input('product_id');$i++) {
      $inventory = Inventory::where('report_id', $report->id)->where('product_id', $request->input('product_id')[$i])->first();
      $inventory->display = $inventory->display = $request->input('display')[$i];
      $inventory->storage = $inventory->storage = $request->input('storage')[$i];          
      $inventory->save();
    }
```

Comment: I had a mistype and changed for($i=0; $i<count(request->input('product_id');$i++) {   .. to ...for($i=0; $i<count($request->input('product_id');$i++) {

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. It's actually working now. Is there any difference if I use get() instead of first()?

Comment: get() might get you a collection of models while first() will get you, for sure, one instance of a model.